# How to connect to PHP my admin database knowing a server's name

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

So I'm trying to help making a website for one of my friend.

I'm trying to connect to his phpmyadmin database via php but I'm failing strong.

All the information I know is his webserver ftp where I can manage the code via WinSCP, the username and password of it which looks like

(not valid links)

"company.myfriend.com/new_website"

and that he has the php my admin

"company.myfriend.com/phpmyadmin" (The username and password of it is the same as the ftp's).

So far I tried

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password" )
```

but I got the error

> Could not connect Access denied for user 'new_website'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

and

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("company.myfriend.com", "username", "password" )
```

but the same error code came and I'm totally lost.

Comment: _Side note:_ PHPMyAdmin is just a web based admin gui written in PHP for managing MySQL databases. Your application talks to MySQL directly and has nothing to do with PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: The error message suggests you're trying to connect using invalid username/password. Make sure you're using the correct credentials. You need to ask your friend about those or you won't be able to connect to the database.

Comment: Aren't the username and password of the phpmyadmin login page and the mysql itself should be the same?

Comment: Probably. But the error message is saying that the user `new_website` with that password doesn't have access to that server. There isn't really much we can do about that. Since the question is about how you access a specific hosting providers services, you need to talk to them.

Comment: In addition to the things already excellently stated by Magnus Eriksson, you can find the current MySQL host from the main page of phpMyAdmin; since you have access to his phpMyAdmin you should be able to see those details once you log in. And as SuperBlaze correctly states, the username and password you use to log in to phpMyAdmin are the MySQL credentials, so you already know the username and password. The host (and socket path or port, which is probably the default of 3306) will be easy to retrieve from the phpMyAdmin page. But just ask his hosting provider, that's what they're there for!